# docker: Forward port to host with net=container:vpn

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

I wish to connect Docker running Firefox to a VPN network, while forwarding the firefox container port to my host (and exposing to my local network):

```
docker create --net=container:vpn -d jlesage/firefox
```

But recieve the following error :

> Error response from daemon: conflicting options: port publishing and
>   the container type network mode

Is there a way around this? Is it even possible?